# Javascript functions related to HTML/CSS elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

**FIXED! I CHANGED "#slide" to ".slide", that was the problem. Thanks everyone!**

Hello, people of Stack Overflow. I have encountered a problem with my code, and it doesn't seem to be hiding the elements when it should be.
Javascript:

```
let sliderImages = document.querySelectorAll('#slide'),
     arrowRight = document.querySelector(".next"),
     arrowLeft = document.querySelector(".prev"),
     current = 0;
//            reset all images
function reset(){
    for(let i = 0; i < sliderImages.length; i++){ 
        // "let" means make a variable which will only be used in the LOCAL scope.
        sliderImages[i].style.display = "none";
    }
}
function startSlide(){
    reset();
}
startSlide();
function test(){
    console.log("hello!") // to prove that this file is running
}
test();
```

The result I'm expecting is for all the images/things with div "#slide" to be invisible.

Instead, I get no change on the webpage. If posting the HTML would help, I will. I have checked, and I believe there to be no typos in the names.

Comment: `id` is supposed to be uniques on a page. Can you also post the corresponding HTML and also how you are including the script ?

Comment: Any errors in your console? Where in the document is your `<script>` tag, in the `<head>` or `<body>`? If `<body>`, where exactly?

Comment: instead of `querySelectorAll` use `getElementById` and be sure you are using `#slide` once in your DOM

Comment: @ColinCline Why would OP use getElementById when they want multiple elements? (hence the for loop) The OP needs to use a class....

Comment: @epascarello Is OP said he need multiple slider in one page?

Comment: sliderImages is the list of slides/images.... read the code.

Comment: @epascarello Op mentioned code is wrong not typo, so obviously i started troubleshooting code based on correct type (we don't know OP's condition, maybe he should use #id for some reason specifically when he says #slide has no problem [in last lines])

Answer (score 2):

Element IDs must be [unique on the page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id). You seem to have more than one `#slide`, so my suggestion is to change from ID to class, so your divs will be:

```
<div class="slide">...</div>
```

This way, you can select them by simply using:

```
let sliderImages = document.querySelectorAll('.slide');
```

Then iterating over them with:

```
sliderImages.forEach(function(sliImg) {
  sliImg.style.display = "none";
});
```

Comment: FYI, `NodeList.prototype.forEach` has [limited browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach#Browser_Compatibility) at this time